# Promise chaining in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am bit confused about the Promise chaining in AWS Lambda.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
firstMethod = ()=>{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve({data: '123'})
        }, 2000);
    });

}
secondMethod = (someStuff)=>{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve({newData:someStuff.data + ' some more data'})
        }, 2000);
    });

}
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        firstMethod().
        then((data)=>{
            console.log("firtMethod data ",JSON.stringify(data));
            secondMethod(data);
        }).
        then((data)=>{
            console.log("second Method data",JSON.stringify(data));
            resolve("final data",data);
        });

    });
    
}
```

I am expecting above code to get output of the firstMethod first and then secondMethod. **But i am getting second method data as undefined.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that your fulfillment handler on the promise from `firstMethod` doesn't return anything. If you want it to return the promise from `secondMethod` so that the chain waits on that promise, you need to do that explicitly:

```
firstMethod().
then((data)=>{
    console.log("firtMethod data ",JSON.stringify(data));
    return secondMethod(data);
//  ^^^^^^
}).
then((data)=>{
    console.log("second Method data",JSON.stringify(data));
    resolve("final data",data);
});
```

**But**, there are some other things you should probably fix as well.

First, you haven't declared either `firstMethod` or `secondMethod`, which means that code is falling prey to what I call *The Horror of Implicit Globals*. Declare your variables.

Second, you're passing more than one argument to `resolve`:

```
resolve("final data",data);
```

`resolve` ignores all arguments except the first one.

Third, your code is using the [promise creation anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You already have a promise from `firstMethod`, you don't need to create a new promise. Just chain off the one you already have.

Instead of:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    firstMethod().
    then((data)=>{
        console.log("firtMethod data ",JSON.stringify(data));
        return secondMethod(data);
    }).
    then((data)=>{
        console.log("second Method data",JSON.stringify(data));
        resolve("final data",data);
    });
});
```

in a non-`async` function you'd use:

```
return firstMethod().
    then((data)=>{
        console.log("firtMethod data ",JSON.stringify(data));
        return secondMethod(data);
    }).
    then((data)=>{
        console.log("second Method data",JSON.stringify(data));
        return "final data");
    });
```

This also has the advantage of ensuring that rejections are passed back to the caller for the caller to handle.

**But**, since your wrapper function is an `async` function, you can use `await` instead of explicitly consuming the promises:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const firstMethod = ()=>{
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({data: '123'})
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
    const secondMethod = (someStuff)=>{
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve({newData:someStuff.data + ' some more data'})
            }, 2000);
        });
    };
    const data = await firstMethod();
    console.log("firtMethod data ",JSON.stringify(data));
    await secondMethod(data);
    console.log("second Method data",JSON.stringify(data));
    return "final data";
};
```